# Delete ListView element

Tags: android, listview

I am reading information from a textfile and showing it on ListView. Now, I need to add a functionality such that the file a user can delete any record from the listview. How do I update the txt file data after a record has been deleted.Please let me know any other alternate way of this implementation.

```
System.out.println("history"+readed);
            tokens = readed.split("\\$");

            if(tokens.length>0)
            {
                data = new Vector<RowData>();
                for(int iTmp=tokens.length-1;iTmp>=0;iTmp--)
                {
                    demo = tokens[iTmp].split("\\@");
                    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$HISTORY is"+demo[0]+""+demo[1]+" "+ReadCountry());
                    try {
                        rd=new RowData(demo[0], demo[1], ReadCountry());
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    data.add(rd);
                }
            }

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.firstlist,R.id.title, data);
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Your description is not clear. Please clarify it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete record from ListView, you have to delete this record from Vector and then:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

While removing the text from the listview, you have to delete the data of that position from your ArrayList also.

Do this:

*data.remove(`[pass the position here]`)*

and then do this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```